# Core Animation retargeting (in iOS?)

Tags: ios, animation, user-interface, core-animation

I'm reasonably new to iOS/Obj-C/Cocoa development (day 5!), so I'm sure I'm probably missing something basic here, but anyway…

Say I have an animation (a `CABasicAnimation`) to change the `position.y` property of my `CALayer`. I set the `duration` to 10 seconds, and start the animation. 5 seconds later, due to user interaction, I want to change the destination `position.y` of the animation.

I have tried two approaches:

1. Change the `toValue` of the in-flight animation

   This simply resulted in no change to the animation (though obviously it "jumped" to the actual position when it was over)
2. Cancel the running animation (`removeAnimationForKey:`), and start a new one. The issue here is I have no way to get the *current* `position.y` from the running animation for the new animation.

I see (brief/vague) [mention](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/CoreAnimationOverview/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010254-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4) of "animation retargeting" in the Core Animation documentation for OS X, but no such mention in iOS.

Is this possible?

Comment: try to start the next animation with `fromValue = [[layer presentationLayer] position].y;`

Comment: @phix23 Thank you, perfect. I had read about the distinction between render/presentation/layer trees, but didn't know there was a way to access values in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try to start the next animation with fromValue = [[layer presentationLayer] position].y;

(as answered in the comments above by @phix23)